# Remove trailing white-spaces from each line in a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-handling

I am using ruby and I want to remove trailing white-spaces at the end of each line in a file.

One way to do this,
iterate line by line and save it in another file and then replace new file with the old one.

```
  temp_file = Tempfile.new("temp")
  f.each_line do |line|
    new_line = line.rstrip
    temp_file.puts  new_line
  end
```

but this is not what I want.
I want to use the method which we generally use in C,C++ without using any temporary file that is, move file pointer to the front of line by new line and overwrite it.

How can we do this in ruby ??

Comment: Why do you "want to use the method which we generally use in C,C++ without using any temporary file"?

Comment: “method which we generally use in C,C++...” – can you provide an example of this method? Note that the Ruby IO API fairly closely matches the C API, so you should be able to do anything you can do in C with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one way to modify the file content in place.

```
# a.rb
File.open "#{__dir__}/out1.txt", 'r+' do |io|
  r_pos = w_pos = 0

  while (io.seek(r_pos, IO::SEEK_SET); io.gets)
    r_pos = io.tell
    io.seek(w_pos, IO::SEEK_SET)
    # line read in by IO#gets will be returned and also assigned to $_.
    io.puts $_.rstrip
    w_pos = io.tell
  end

  io.truncate(w_pos)
end
```

Here is the output of the file.

```
[arup@Ruby]$ cat out1.txt
 foo 
    biz
 bar

[arup@Ruby]$ ruby a.rb
[arup@Ruby]$ cat out1.txt
 foo
    biz
 bar

[arup@Ruby]$
```

Comment: looking fine, use rstrip instead of just strip because I want to remove trailing white-spaces and not from the beginning.

Comment: Just do little change as below to avoid infinity loop.
    `while (io.seek(r_pos, IO::SEEK_SET); io.gets)
          r_pos = io.tell
          io.seek(w_pos, IO::SEEK_SET)
          if io.eof?
             break
          end
          io.puts $_.rstrip
          w_pos = io.tell
    end`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
file_name = 'testFile.txt'

input_content = File.open(file_name).read
output_content = []

file.each_line do |line|
  line.gsub!("\n",'').strip!
  output_content << line
end

File.open(file_name,'w').write(output_content.join("\n"))
```